# solaris + grep syntax in solaris

Tags: solaris, grep

my target is to match Exactly the string snmpmanager from hosts file on solaris & linux

the following command work on Linux (red-hat 5.1) but not for SunOS , please advice how to fit the syntax to solaris?

example from solaris OS

```
   grep -icE '(^|[[:space:]])snmpmanager($|[[:space:]])' /etc/hosts
   grep: illegal option -- E
```

after I fixed it to

```
       egrep -i '(^|[[:space:]])snmpmanager($|[[:space:]])'  /etc/hosts
  or   egrep -i '(^|[\s])snmpmanager($|\s])'  /etc/hosts
  or   egrep -i '(^|[\t])snmpmanager($|\t])'  /etc/hosts
```

but I don’t get any match output (but snmpmanager already defined in host file)  ??

my host file

```
     10.170.10.5      loghost
     10.170.10.61   Master SyslogSer vip Tcc NtpServer1 NtpServer2 snmpManager snmpManagerPA1 snmpManagerPA2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the standard Solaris (e)grep understands the `[[:space:]]` syntax so you would have to use something like

```
egrep -i (^| |<-TAB->)snmpmanager($| |<-TAB->)
```

where `<-TAB->` is <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

If you use /usr/xpg4/bin/egrep then it works as expected.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep -i '([[:space:]])snmpmanager($|[[:space:]])'  /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I find the solution for solaris its -  grep -iwc snmpManager (only need to add w flag)

Answer (score 1):

use `egrep -ic` instead of `grep -icE`.  Note that -i is making the match case insensitive, which may or may not be what you want depending on your definition of "Exactly"

Comment: I try this on my solaris --> egrep -ic '(^|[[:space:]])snmpManager($|[[:space:]])' /etc/hosts 0 (why this not match the snmpManager string that already defined in host file

Comment: try replacing `[[:space:]]` with either `\s` or `[ \t]`

Comment: Also check the options: do a `man egrep` on Solaris and check to see what they do. Make sure that your invocation is using the right options.

Comment: egrep -i '(^|[\t])snmpmanager($|\t])'  /etc/hosts or egrep -i '(^|[\s])snmpmanager($|\s])'  /etc/hosts not give any output also -:(

Comment: that `[ \t]` should have a space before the \t

Comment: I find the solution for solaris its -  grep -iwc snmpManager (only need to add w flag)

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally (such as exists in Solaris) there were three alternate versions of `grep`: there was also `egrep`, `fgrep`, and `rgrep`.

According to POSIX, these three variants are now included as options to `grep`:

- `egrep` is equivalent to `grep -E`
- `fgrep` is equivalent to `grep -F`
- `rgrep` is equivalent to `grep -r`

Thus, with your invocation, you want this:

```
egrep -ic '(^|[[:space:]])snmpmanager($|[[:space:]])' /etc/hosts
```

(This assumes there aren't other errors.)

Comment: I find the solution for solaris its -  grep -iwc snmpManager (only need to add w flag)

Answer (score 1):

Solaris grep is not the GNU grep from coreutils, so the behavior in more complex cases is likely to be different.

One idea would be installing GNU grep. If you install the ggrep package from OpenCSW, it will install the GNU grep as `/opt/csw/bin/ggrep` with an additional symlink in `/opt/csw/gnu/grep`.

First you bootstrap pkgutil:

```
wget http://mirror.opencsw.org/opencsw/pkgutil.pkg
pkgadd -d pkgutil.pkg
pkgutil -U
```

Now you can install GNU grep:

```
pkgutil -y -i ggrep
```

You can add `/opt/csw/gnu` to your `PATH`, which will allow you to use the `grep` command the same way as on Linux.

If you want to use it your script, you can write:

```
/opt/csw/bin/ggrep -icE '(^|[[:space:]])snmpmanager($|[[:space:]])' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

The manpage of grep in Solaris 11 pointed to `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`if we want to use the `-E`
I tried it and it worked in my case.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E "DisplayConnect[[:space:]]*/etc/issue" /etc/proftpd.conf
DisplayConnect      /etc/issue
```